# Is it possible to have 2 wireless interfaces and have each interface connect to a different VPN over a MacPro?

Tags: network, vpn, macos, mac

Is it possible to have 2 wireless interfaces and have each interface connect to a different VPN over a MacPro?

Basically, I have a MacPro with 2 wireless interfaces. I connected to both wireless networks, and would like each network interface to be able to VPN to 2 different VPNs.

I was wondering if that was even possible. Currently, when I connect to one wireless network via Cisco IPSec VPN it forces all traffic through that one interface. And was wondering if I had a 2nd wireless interface would I be able to connect to the network to a different VPN.

Comment: Could you edit this to explain how you have created 2 wireless interfaces on the Mac Pro?

Answer (score 0):

The problem of Cisco VPN rules forcing all traffic through the VPN is a long-standing pain in the neck. You may find this post helpful in manually adding routing rules:

https://superuser.com/questions/91191/how-to-force-split-tunnel-routing-on-mac-to-a-cisco-vpn

Good luck with it!